# Relationship between Asymptotic bounds and Running time?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Lets Take Binary search for instance, The best case running time would be obtained in First comparison when

> key_to_find == (imin + imax) / 2;

And the best case running time would be represented by O(1). I Completely understand that but what confuses me is why O(1) is used and why I can't use Θ(1) or any other notation for same.

i.e . How to identify which notation should I use to represent the Running time(Best, Average or Worst case).

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to talk about the best case. The best case can almost always be made very fast. It means nothing.

Comment: Rephrasing myself : How to identify which notation should I use to represent the Running time(Best, Average or Worst case)?

Comment: You should not waste your time on the best case. It's not interesting. It's not important. It makes no sense to ever start talking about it. As for choice of notation for other cases, it depends on what do you want to say. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) has it all. Normally Θ is most useful and precise so use it whenever you can.

Comment: You can use Theta for whichever case you want as long as Big Theta actually applies for that function. Big O and Big Theta has no ties to which case you are talking about. As a rule of thumb, you find the Big O of the running time of the worst case, and then that Big O describes the running time in all cases (because it is an upper bound). The biggest issues you should find in using Big Theta for run time is when you are using it to describe all cases. Insertion sort can run linearly or quadratically, so you can describe it's runtime in all cases with one Big Theta, but you could for MergeSort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O-notation and Θ-notation are not directly related to best-case, average or worst case.
They are use for asymptotic bounds of functions.
You can write:
47n lg n = O(n lg n),
3n^2 + 4n = O(n^2)

And there is a difference between O a Θ notation. O means "at most (using some constant factor)", Θ means "equal (using some constant factor)", e.g.:
47n ln n = O(n^2), but it's not Θ(n^2).

If you want to express best case, average case or worst case, you usually write them explicitly:
"Best case is O(1) (or Θ(1)), average case is O(lg n), worst case is O(n)."

Sometimes you also "running time is O(x)", then you mean, running time is at most proportional to x. If you say "running time is Θ(x)", then you mean, running time is always proportional to x.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any notation you want. Big Theta is the most precise so you should use it whenever you know it. As a side note, O(1) is equivalent to Θ(1) in the context of complexity analysis (where the number of operations is an integer, i.e. one cannot have O(1/n) as a complexity).

Comment: "O(1) is equivalent to Θ(1)." - no it's not

Comment: In the context of complexity analysis (where the number of operations is an integer, i.e. you cannot have O(1/n) as a complexity) I believe it is. Could you please provide an example in which it is not the case?

Comment: n ln n = O(n^2) but not Θ(n^2)

Comment: I agree with @FranckDernoncourt, though you should should probably abstain from calling them equivalent, because they do not describe the same set of functions. You made your point clearly, though, and that's of course what is important.

Comment: I have edited my answer to explicit the context (i.e. the set of functions we are in).